# Skyrim thieves guild 4 special quest done

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have finished all 4 special quests for Delvin but I'm not becoming the Guild Master.  I am playing it on PS4 and version 1.07

Answer (score 2):

The four special quests, triggered by doing the radiant quests from Vex and Delvin, are not the quests to become the guild master.

The [main quests](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_(faction)#Primary_Quests) for the Thieves' Guild are as follows:

- A Chance Arrangement
- Taking Care of Business
- Loud and Clear
- Dampened Spirits
- Scoundrel's Folly
- Speaking With Silence
- Hard Answers
- The Pursuit
- Trinity Restored
- Blindsighted
- Darkness Returns
- Under New Management

Comment: Your 1st paragraph is, at this time, incorrect.  The 4 special quests are simply half the answer.

Comment: "Under New Management" - This quest is the one to go: http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Under_New_Management
If you do enough jobs offered by Delvin and Vex you can also "Restore the glory of the thieves guild".

Answer (score 1):

The 4 special quests are important for restoring the Thieves' Guild's status in Skyrim.  Good Start.

The Guild's Main Quest-line (as delineated in Nelson's answer) is how you deal with the fact that, as Delvin Mallory so quaintly puts it, "Somethin' out there is piss-drunk mad at us."

Once you have dealt with *both* of these issues, you can become Guild Master.